# Check if PHP-FPM is working

Tags: php, nginx

I have just installed Plesk 12, which comes inbuilt with an nginx server over an apache server. On enabling PHP-FPM, i cannot see it mentioned using the **phpinfo();** function...thought the website works just fine.

Also, on trying these -

1.) telnet 127.0.0.1 9000

**Result** =

```
telnet: could not resolve 127.0.0.1/:9000: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

2.) ps -ef | grep php-fpm

**Result** =

```
root      3188     1  0 03:23 ?        00:00:01 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf) www-data  3194  3188  0 03:23 ?   00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www                  www-data  3195  3188  0 03:23 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www                  root      6044  5140  0 12:23 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
```

3.) netstat -tlpn | grep :9000

**Result** = No result

I'm not sure if something is wrong, or if PHP-FPM is working correctly. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Well if the website is working and you can serve `phpinfo();` from nginx, then I'd say php-fpm is working ...

Comment: Hello naomik, thank you for your reply. But nginx can serve even without php-fpm isn't it

Comment: Hi! In general Plesk uses Unix socket for communication between webserver and php-fpm, so probe TCP port does nothing. Your might check the **Server API** on your phpinfo page, and it shoud be **FPM/FastCGI** in case of php-fpm enabled

Comment: Hello Michael. My Server API show "CGI/FastCGI" in the results from phpinfo(); ..so the PHP-FPM is not working afterall?

Comment: @codemode nah, I doubt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution - When I go to my Plesk's Web server settings, there is a checkbox that says "Process PHP by Nginx". Check that, and the `phpinfo();` shows the Server API as FPM/FastCGI now!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have installed and activated the PHP-FPM module like described in the Plesk Administration Guide under the section PHP-FPM.

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=70669.htm][1]

Check the status of PHP-FPM:

```
sudo service php5-fpm status
```

Should output something like this:

```
php5-fpm start/running, process 1094
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your input. Yes, "service php5-fpm status" and "ps -ef | grep php-fpm" do give a positive response. But, not telnet ,netstat or phpinfo(); .. which is my confusion.

Comment: Maybe you are using fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; and not fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;